# Python least squares regression qs

Tags: python, regression

Why doesn't this code work? I am trying to do multi-variate regression.
Four equations of the form:

```
Ax + By + c = d

A + 2B + C = 0.2 etc.

A = np.array([[ 0.,  1, 1.],
   [ 1.,  2, 1.],
   [ 2.,  3, 1.],
   [ 3.,  4, 1.]])

y = np.array([-1, 0.2, 0.9, 2.1])
m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]
print m, c
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Error? Bad output? Show us!

Comment: Try it yourself and figure out. I gave the code. nnatarr - thanks for answering!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you took `m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]` line from the `lstsq` [example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html). 
In the example they are solving linear regression problem with **one** variable and constant. As the result, `np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)` for this problem returns four-element tuple `(array([ 1.  , -0.95]), array([ 0.05]), 2, array([ 4.10003045,  1.09075677]))` (first element – solution, second – residuals, third – the coefficient matrix rank, last element – singular values of coefficient matrix).
So, `np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]` (in the example) returns array with two elements which can be unpacked the way they are doing it: `m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]` (`m = 1., c = -0.95`).

You are solving regression with **two** variables and constant. Therefore, `np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]` will return array with three elements and if you want to unpack it the way it was in the example you can do it this way:

```
x1, x2, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]
```

But more convenient way would be (in my opinion):

```
x, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y) #lstsq func always return four-element tuple

print 'solution is %s.' % str(x)
print 'matrix A rank is %d.' % rank
print 'residuals are %s.' % str(residuals)
print 'singular values of A are %s.' % str(s)

print 'first variable is %f.' % x[0]
print 'second variable is %f.' % x[1]
print 'constant is %f.' % x[2]
```